# Gratis WebAssembly IDE

Tags: windows, gratis, c, webassembly

I realize that [WebAssembly](http://webassembly.org/) is in its infancy still, but , as I normally code embedded C (and, occasionally, C++) for a living, I would like to get started. It will be very interesting for me personally to see how I can use it with AngularJs.

Does anyone know of a [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis) IDE which supports http://webassembly.org/?

***Must have***

- supports C
- lets me set breakpoints and stop in the C code, examine stack, examine & change variables, all the usual debuggy things
- free for commercial use (in case I decide to use it on a side gig)
- runs on Windows

***Nice to have***

- runs on Linux

  - normal IDE features, such as auto-complete, refactoring, etc, etc

I am not asking for too much, as it is very early days yet. I would prefer it if you have actual experience of your recommendation, rather that having simply Googled for it.

---

[Update] a stand-alone IDE may not be necessary (eventually). Point 6 of [this article](https://auth0.com/blog/7-things-you-should-know-about-web-assembly) says

> Fact 6: Source-maps will allow you to easily debug compiled code in
>   the browser
>
> One of the downsides of a compiled target-language is that debugging
>   usually gets harder. If you have played with any language that
>   currently translates to JavaScript, you might have experienced
>   debugging hell when trying to mentally map the resulting code to your
>   original code. WebAssembly aims to be a great platform for other
>   languages, so a solution for this is already being developed. Much
>   like current native compilers, WebAssembly will allow for debugging
>   information in its binary format along with source maps. Source maps
>   will tell browsers and debuggers how to map the generated code to its
>   original source representation. Easy debugging is part of the
>   WebAssembly spec.

---

[Update++] I found [this question)([Looking for a solution to run Python the browser](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/58412/looking-for-a-solution-to-run-python-the-browser/)) which made me want to search for a webassembly IDE, which led me to stumble over this old question, which never received any feedback. Surely there is some webassembly IDE?

Comment: I am currently looking at https://webassembly.studio/