# Looking for a solution to run Python the browser

Tags: gratis, python, webassembly

[Mozilla details Pyodide, which brings Python to browsers](https://venturebeat.com/2019/04/16/mozilla-details-pyodide-a-project-that-aims-to-bring-python-to-web-browsers/) caught my eye.

However, it is not quite stable, according to the article.

Is there a gratis, stable, popular and well supported means of running Python as Web Assembly?

Obviously, without a good IDE, including debugger, it won't be of much use.

Comment: Not WebAssembly, but [Brython](http://brython.info/) is another setup for using Python in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not expect any Python runtime in Wbassembly production-grade stable yet. Webassembly came out 2 years ago. [Pyodide](https://github.com/iodide-project/pyodide) (supported by Mozilla) is the most well supported Python AFAIK.

BTW, have you actually tried Pyodide? It runs quite well in my computer.

Comment: Nope, I only read of it yesterday. I will give it a spin over the holiday weekend. I am a very reluctant JS coder, and would much rater code C, or Python or Ada, but now we enter fantasy land ;-).

Comment: Hmm, I think that I will wait until there is a decent IDE which lets me test my web assembly in the actual browser code - unless you know of one?

Comment: please see https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/47418/gratis-webassembly-ide